# Understanding inheritance in php

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I'm new to using OOP in PHP (And in general) and I had a question about inheritance.

I have the following classes:

```
class OCITable {
  public function display() {
    $this->drawHeader();
    $this->drawFooter();
    $this->drawBody();
  }

  private function drawHeader() {
    ...
  }

  private function drawFooter() {
    ...
  }

  private function drawBody() {
    ...
  }
}

class OCITableServer extends OCITable {
  private function drawBody() {
    ...
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is overrule the private function `drawBody()`. This doesn't seem to work. I think this is because when a `OCITableServer` object calls `display()`, it calls the parent class's `display()`, which in turn calls its `drawBody()`, instead of the new `drawBody()`.

How would I accomplish what I'm trying to do without redefining `display()` in my sub class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Protected` methods can be overridden in subclasses.  Private functions cannot.