# PHP Variables, classes and inheritance understanding the basics

Tags: php, class, variables, inheritance

I am working on a PHP project and I need some help with the basics. I have a Vehicle class. Within the vehicle class there is a variable called fuel_capacity. As you would expect the fuel capacity changes from vehicle to vehicle. So for example the fuel_capacity changes between a car and a truck. I have a Car class and a Truck class that extend the vehicle class.

On construction of the car I want to assign $fuel_capacity a value. When I do this I can not access $fuel_capacity from the functions within vehicle unless I declare $fuel_capacity public. The problem is if I declare $fuel_capacity public in the Car class then I am worried it will conflict with the $fuel_capacity for the Truck class. Is this correct? If so how do I share the $fuel_capacity with the parent?

Also I want to use a constructor class in my Car class then this overrides my Vehicle class constructor. Is there anyway that I can call for example assign a value such as $fuel_capacity within the Car class and then use that value within the constructor of the Vehicle class?

Finally is there a way to setup an interface for a class that extends from another class?

I have looked at many pages including [What's the difference between using normal functions and class methods in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539778/help-understanding-php-classes), [Understanding inheritance in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535172/understanding-inheritance-in-php), [Understanding PHP Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796907/understanding-php-inheritance), and [What's the difference between using normal functions and class methods in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539778/help-understanding-php-classes). These have all been great introduction but they don't address these questions. Thanks :-)

Comment: Have you read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php ?

Comment: Yes @Cory :-) it is because I don't understand that I am asking these questions.

Comment: You sound like you have a Java background. I would recommend forgetting that when you're learning PHP.

Comment: @Jon well PHP's OOP sorta mimics (or copies) Java

Comment: You are spot on @Jon. I will try.

Comment: @g13n true, but the way you use PHP becomes very confusing if you try and think about it like it's Java. I know from trying to learn them at the same time. While a lot of theory and structure is the same, the applications are completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to really understand how OOP works and how it is implemented in PHP.  http://php.net/oop should be able to help.

Here's one way to do it.  You can of course set the fuel capacity in constructor.  I recommend `Vehicle` to be an `abstract` class since you don't want someone to create a `Vehicle` object.

If you inherit of course you can access the variable from `Car/Trunk` classes since its declared protected.

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    public function setFuelCapacity($capacity) {
        $this->fuel_capacity = $capacity;
    }

    protected $fuel_capacity;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
}

class Truck extends Vehicle {
}
```

Hope that helps.